# mvc4 Insert to table with data from another table

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my model:

```
 public class Categories
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string  Name { get; set; }
                public UserProfile User { get; set; }
            }


        public class Profits
            {
                [Key]
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public double Value { get; set; }
                public string Description{ get; set; }
                public DateTime DateInput { get; set; }
                public UserProfile User { get; set; } // Foreign to User
                public Categories CategoryName { get; set; } // Foreign  to Categories
            }
```

now i want to do in my View something like "insert into Profits("column names") values ("Take from textBoxes" and Category from DropdownList with data from Categories Table)"

My logic is every profit have one category ( salary,jackpot,etc), and every category may have more then one profit . 
What i should do know ?

Comment: Are you just looking for a tutorial on how to bind a view to a model?

Comment: no , i ask are my model is right ?

Comment: I certainly don't see anything wrong with the models.  You say that every `Profits` should refer to exactly one `Categories`, which it does.  Aside from that, there's no way for us to know if your models accurately represent the business concepts they're meant to.  On a purely technical level, they're valid DTO objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one profit in a category, you should use a collection in category with the ids from the profits. So you can access the data faster and without processing too much.